# Nefesh Habahamit/Body of Moshiach

Tags: messiah, soul

I have a bunch of questions about the Nefesh Habahamit (the earthy "animal" soul) of the Moshiach (Ben David). Note, I don't want to limit this just to Kabbalistic/Lurian sources, so I will expand this to include sources that discuss "the body" of Moshiach, in contrast to his soul.

All I am asking here is for any and all sources that discuss and teach about this.

Comment: I know that Tzadikim don't have a yetzer hara. Possibly the same though I don't have a source yet.

Comment: @Moishe I don't think they're synonymous. Tanya [Chapter 29](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=2/20/2024) implies the animal soul still exists, albeit in a sublimated state.

Comment: I think this question may relate to the Reb Tzaddok on this week's sedrah who discusses why we have a *neshama yeseira* and a *ruach yeseirah* on *Shabbos* but not a *nephesh yeseira*.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Please take the time to reflect on your inquiry and express  it in more definable parameters.

Comment: I have taken out the Tanya tag because the concept could arguably be attributed to the Arizal, and to be fair, I would even accept a very old source that doesn't use those terms, but does discuss the "body" vs "the soul" of the Moshiach as well

Comment: @YaacovDeane I would like to learn about the Nefesh Habahamit (the body, and/or earthly soul) of the Moshiach. For example, is that soul unique in any way? What it created in a special way? So many questions like that. My question is actually very focussed as far as I can tell: are there any sources that discuss this? Bringing such a source would be a perfectly fine answer. However, I am open to having my mind changed, if you wish to explain to me what trouble you are having answering it I will gladly edit the question to make it in a more definable way

Comment: I understand that there is a concept that the soul of Moshiach is incarnated in all of the generational Moshiachs, so there is "more than one animal soul", but is there anything general to learn there? I also understand there are several different types of "Moshiach", so I mean Moshiach Ben David, ok?

Comment: If you understand that the Nefesh HaBehamit is the ממוצע המחבר, like is taught in Chassidut, and you know that the creation of Moshiach is at the very beginning of the first day of creation, like is stated in the first 2 lines of the Torah, then the answer to your question is in reflecting (meditating) on that alone. To put it another way, that interface point is the Tzim-tzum HaRishon, which pertains to the inner 2 letters of G-d's six letter name.

Comment: @YaacovDeane that's exactly what I am looking for, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In this video there is discussed the possibility of משיח falling.

https://youtu.be/IWiMvuVkB1A?si=ZaRQqAiDYuNXpsQx

The whole video series is about how משיח lifts up all those who fell before him but it also calls him בר נפלא.

Not 100% what you asked but I think its close enough.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting (cut off just when it was getting extra good!)

Comment: @RabbiKaii its a series of multiple videos